# Using a Raspberry Pi as an access point redirects to an HTML website stored on a hard drive connected via USB

Tags: wifi, pi-4, web-server, html5

I would like to code a very simple web site in HTML/CSS/JS that is stored on a hard disc (because it’s heavy with some media video) connected to my Raspberry Pi 4 and give local access to this website via a WIFI hotspot.

For example, When John opens his laptop or phone, he sees the network named `MyWIFINetwork`. He connects to it, and when he connects to it, it redirects him automatically to the site (whose code is stored on the hard drive) `mywifinetwork.local`.

I have a lot of tracks (apache server, LAMP, `hostpad` etc.) but I would like to have your opinion on what is the most simple or efficient way to do this.

I want to keep that simple to be able to explain it to people to make them able to make their own ( the website stored on is a project that wants to make some knowledge available locally completely independent from the internet).

Thanks in advance and apologies if my questions are stupid.

Comment: Looks like you want to create a 'captive portal'. Try searching the internet for examples / instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a raspberry pi as a Access point is very easy these days I recommend the snap wifi-ap application.

I've always setup access points using hostapd, dnsmasqd by hand and this application makes it as simple as installing and configuring which can be done in a few minutes.

[Howto install wifi-ap](https://snapcraft.io/install/wifi-ap/ubuntu)

Once you have it installed you can run:-
wifi-ap-config get

This will show you the defaults, just use:-
wifi-ap-config set wifi.ssid

The trick to having a captive HTTP server is you redirect all of the traffic to your own web server on your wifi-ap node by setting up a DNS server.

Here is a GitHub link that details how to setup a dnsmasqd captive portal.
[Howto setup a Captive portal](https://github.com/levexis/captive-portal)

Comment: Many thanks to you, you make it clear !

I have some struggles to get how the captive portal can redirect to an harddrive connected to my Raspberry but I'm gonna dig for that thanks again for your time and pedagogy !

Comment: No problem.. the wifi-ap is very easy but the captive portal is non-trivial..

Comment: Another useful tool is avahi .   It can allow you to advertise your hostnames via zeroconf (also known as bonjour).    But it doesn't work with Windows without extensions but is brilliant for Linux and Macs.